# Jboss 7.1.1.Final - Stream closed

Tags: java, jboss, ubuntu-16.04

I have problem when I try to upload .war file through jboss console. Sometimes it works but mostly doesn't. Jboss try to upload file 2-3 times and return warning. File size is about 135 mb. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
14:22:57,329 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 24) JBAS015891: Caught exception closing input stream for uploaded deployment content: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.FixedLengthInputStream.readImpl(FixedLengthInputStream.java:54)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.LeftOverInputStream.drain(LeftOverInputStream.java:112)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.LeftOverInputStream.close(LeftOverInputStream.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.multipart.BoundaryDelimitedInputStream.close(BoundaryDelimitedInputStream.java:213) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.AbstractDeploymentUploadHandler.safeClose(AbstractDeploymentUploadHandler.java:77) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.AbstractDeploymentUploadHandler.execute(AbstractDeploymentUploadHandler.java:62) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:466) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:121) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$1.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:309) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$1.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:299) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.processUploadRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:247) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.doHandle(DomainApiHandler.java:181) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handle(DomainApiHandler.java:208) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handle(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:51) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:710)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.RealmReadinessFilter.doFilter(RealmReadinessFilter.java:54) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
```

Comment: It's likely trying to deploy the WAR file while it's still being uploaded.  That is a rather large file though.  What about putting much of the larger JAR libraries in the lib folder of JBoss to minimize your WAR size? Further research suggests it was a bug that was rectified in 7.1.2 - can you possibly upgrade to that version?

Comment: I have to stay at full size file because we using bamboo to deploying app on several servers. I was looking for official 7.1.2 version but I didn't find. Where can I get jboss 7.1.2?

Comment: And you're referring to Community Version and not Enterprise version (EAP)?

Comment: It looks like 7.1.2 got rolled up into EAP 6 so there isnt an official download.  You probably want to switch to WildFly 8 which is the new name for the AS community edition.  Downloads can be found here http://wildfly.org/downloads/ - since you dont want to possibly introduce any other bugs or headaches - I'd suggest just trying 8.0.0.Final and if that works - you could experiment with going higher until your appas breaks due to using conflicting jars.  Let me know if you get things going!

Comment: You got right it was a bug. Upgrade helped. Thanks.

Comment: While I couldn't provide a useful answer really, just a comment which stinks - glad I could help!